# Defining a default center on Google Maps new layer on QGIS

Tags: qgis

When adding a new layer with Google Maps on a new project on QGIS, I am getting the world map. Is there an option where I can set the default center?

Initial view when adding an XYZ Google Map Tile.

I did this trough adding an XYZ Tile connection with the  Google Maps XYZ Tile URL [https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

[image: Initial view when adding an XYZ Google Map Tile]

I want to know if there is a way to set the view of the Tile like this:

[image: Centered view]

Comment: Can you please describe the way you bring Google Maps into QGIS ? Is it happening via a Plugin or as a TMS ?